# Defining a method - output Dogcatcatdog

Tags: python, procedure

I have tried running the code below. Why does the code not print dogcatcatdog? I have defined a to equal dog as a string and b to equal cat as a string in the main procedure? What am I doing wrong below? My understanding is that it would assign values of dog and cat to A and B and then print the return?

The current code prints out ABBA. If I change the print method to say 
print abbaize('dog','cat') THEN it will print out dogcatcatdog. Why cannot I define it in the main method like I did in my code below?

```
def abbaize(a ='dog', b ='cat'):
    return a + b + b + a
print abbaize('a','b')
```

I expect the code above to print dogcatcatdog?

Comment: You have not "defined a to equal dog as a string and b to equal cat", with `abbaize(a ='dog', b ='cat')` you are just saying `abbaize` has two parameters, `a` and `b`, which are both optional, having default values `'dog'` and `'cat'` respectively. However, when you do `abbaize('a', 'b')` you are passing `'a'` (a string) as value for the parameter `a` and `'b'` as value for the parameter `b`. To use the default values, just do not pass any parameter, call `abbaize()` (or you could pass them again with `abbaize('dog', 'cat')`).

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
print abbaize('a','b')
```

to:

```
print abbaize()
```

If you use your line it would replace the string "dog" with "a".
Since you declared your variables already in the function you dont need to pass them to the function.
Maybe to get a better understanding you could also do this:

```
def abbaize(a, b):
    return a + b + b + a
print abbaize('dog','cat')
```

If you are using Python 3.x you also need to change the print line to:

```
print(abbaize())
```